# How can JVMs running inside Bluemix container groups be monitored?

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud, jmx, websphere-liberty

I am using Liberty inside Bluemix Docker container groups. I want to integrate on premise monitoring tools with these container groups to monitor Liberty JMV.

Using rest adopter, I can do this when we have one member in the group, but not with more than one member in the group as the JMX is exposed through the load balancer. I can not access the container ports directly as these have Bluemix private IPs.

Answer (score 1):

You can get to the private ips, but you'll have to either get in via [the VPN service](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_security_network.html#container_vpn), or via an ssh tunnel through another container in that same space.  That may be the simplest (and most secure) way to access that remotely.